# Skill Not working when deployed using CI/CD Pipelines

Tags: botframework, bots, bot-framework-composer

When I deploy my skill directly from composer to azure Skill works fine and I can see my manifest at the URL for remote skill manifest. But when I deploy my skill using CI/CD Pipelines on the same resources I can see the changes I made to functioning the bot(the bot works fine) but Remote skill URL stops working(I cant see my remote manifest). Can someone help with this.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Comment: Yes it worked @KyleDelaney

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer

Comment: Are you willing to accept my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/8019):

> could you please try to copy the generated manifest/lu files to the wwwroot folder, then it can be accessed by url.